# Can you store scrolls loose in a handy haversack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Can you store loose scrolls in a handy haversack, or do you have to have a scroll case or scroll box?

If not, the action economy would function as such:

1. Use a move to retrieve loose scroll from the haversack.
2. Use a standard to cast a spell

Correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

A [Handy Haversack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-handy-haversack/) has no mention of items in the bag needing special protections for its contents against other items in the bag, nor against environmental issues; nor does the [Bag of Holding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding/) on which it's based.

At least, I see no reason why that wouldn't work. As a GM, I'd have no problem with this (in fact, I'd never thought to question that action economy working exactly as laid out in the question). I suppose issues could arise if the haversack goes underwater unplanned, though (or is opened underwater, generally).